# Iptables unresolved dependencies

Tags: 9.10, iptables

I'm trying to setup OpenVPN Access Server on a  VPS running Ubuntu 9.10 for a friend so she can play games from her uni campus. The problem is I keep running into this error when trying to start openvpn.

```
Service deferred error: IPTablesServiceBase: failed to run iptables-restore [status=1]: ['FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-028stab070.14/modules.dep: No such file or directory', 'FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-028stab070.14/modules.dep: No such file or directory', 'iptables-restore: line 46 failed']: internet/base:1175,internet/base:752,internet/process:45,internet/process:306,internet/_baseprocess:48,internet/process:775,internet/_baseprocess:60,svc/pp:116,svc/svcnotify:26,internet/defer:238,internet/defer:307,internet/defer:323,sagent/ipts:105,sagent/ipts:39,util/error:52,util/error:32
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['iptables_openvpn'])
```

Now I've already got my provider to enabled the TUN/TAP device driver and I checked this using

```
# cat /dev/net/tun
```

Which returned

```
“File descriptor in bad state”
```

Which I believe means it's enabled.

After extensive searching, I've been unable to find any solution other than people suggesting to make sure TUN/TAP device driver is enabled.

Any ideas on how to solve my issue? I'm not very experience with Linux and I feel in over my head here so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the VPS hosted? Output of `uname -r` and `ls /lib/modules`?

Comment: 2.6.18-028stab070.14 and 2.6.18-028stab070.7

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel modules in `/lib/modules` do not match the loaded kernel version.

- Loaded kernel version: 2.6.18-028stab070.**14**
- Kernel modules version: 2.6.18-028stab070.**7**

You should never attempt to load kernel modules which are not compiled for the loaded kernel. A quick [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=2.6.18-028stab070.14) made clear that your kernel (OpenVZ visualization technique?) is a common one.

Try to find the matching kernel modules by running `apt-cache search 'linux-image-*'`. If you cannot find the right kernel, please post the output of the command in your question.

Comment: Am I able to update the modules with OpenVZ or is this something the host needs to do? Been struggling.

Comment: The loaded kernel module is something only the host can change. But the files in `/lib/modules` are under your control. Can you post the output of `apt-cache search 'linux-image-*'`? If the package exist, you are fine. Otherwise, you might want to ask your host for the right package containing the kernel modules.